# C# - ASP.NET - Inserting Date from a calendar into a DataBase

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access, calendar

I am trying to store the date from a calendar which the user has selected into a database.
It seems to not being inserting it into the Access Database.
The DB field data type is Date/Time and the variables are below.
I know my Query works because the other information stores correctly.

```
DateTime dtUserDate;
dtUserDate = calenderUserDate.SelectedDate;

string myQuery = "INSERT INTO MMK( Name, Email, Address, Town, County, PostCode, Country, Telephone, Date Joined)   VALUES ( '" + strName + "' , '" + strEmail + "' , '" + strAddress + "' , '" + strTown + "' , '" + strCounty + "' , '" + strPostCode + "' , '" + strCountry + "' , '" + strTeleNumber + "' , '" + dtUserDate+ "')";
```

Thanks

Comment: "Date Joined" is not a valid field name due to the space, that might be the problem, or maybe just part of it

Comment: You need to read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), because your current code is a security problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
INSERT INTO MMK( Name, Email, Address, Town, County, PostCode, Country, Telephone, [Date Joined]) ....
```

Note that your table column `Date Joined` having space, use `[Date Joined]`

Use Parameters as below

```
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO MMK( Name, Email, Address, Town, County, PostCode, Country, Telephone, [Date Joined])   VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", strName);
    ....
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateJoined", dtUserDate);
```

Comment: Nice, I was thinking about somthing like this: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MMK(Name, Email, Address, Town, County, PostCode, Country, Telephone, [Date Joined])   VALUES(@Name, @Email, @Address, @Town, @County, @PostCode, @Country, @TeleNumber, @UserDate", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.String).Value = strName;
[...]
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = calenderUserDate.SelectedDate;`

Comment: @Dawid the OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters, please check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ( cc: @Dawid ) IMO that page is slightly misleading when it says that "the question mark (?) placeholder must be used". I have found that we *can* use `@Names` instead of `?` as long as we bear in mind that OleDb **ignores** the names and only relies on the *position* of the parameters in the CommandText, i.e. "the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the ... placeholder for the parameter in the command text."